# current page style in wordpress with html 5 blank

Tags: wordpress, themes, nav

anybody knows the blank theme html5 for wordpress? well i'm using this theme and i'm trying to add some style to the current page but i don't know how.
this is the function that the theme has:

```
function html5blank_nav()
{
wp_nav_menu(
array(
    'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
    'menu'            => '', 
    'container'       => 'div', 
    'container_class' => 'menu-{menu slug}-container', 
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu', 
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
    )
);
 }
```

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

See your question is not clear enough!! The above code is for styling the nav menus,

Here you can change the menu class, the container and lot more!!

Comment: i'm sorry if don´t be clear, i talked about a wordpress theme and the code above is the function that the theme has, i want to create the functionality active link. Is difficult to explain because in the html there is the function called `<?php html5blank_nav(); ?>`. Thank you

Comment: Can you please send me the site URL??

Anyways here is the sample css for active link on wordpress:

.current-menu-item

.current_page_item

Use some thing like this

.current-menu-item a { background: red; }

Comment: yes i don't have a problem to implement your idea because i have already did this with the tipical nav in html, but with functions and clases in wordpress is a lillte confusing. thanks anyway.